# Using another method in main method

Tags: java

Hello everyone I am in need of some help. First let me provide some code:

```
public class AccountTest {
public static void main(String[]args){
    Account account1 = new Account("Jane Green", 50.00);
    Account account2 = new Account("John Blue", -7.53);

    System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n", account1.getName(), account1.getBalance); //13-14 
    System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n", account2.getName(), account2.getBalance);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter deposit amount for account1: ");
    double depositAmount = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.printf("%nadding %.2f to account1 balance%n%n", depositAmount);
    account1.deposit(depositAmount);

    System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n", displayAccount(account1)); //28-29
    System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n", displayAccount(account2)); //30-31

    System.out.print("Enter deposit amount for account2: ");
    double depositAmount2 = input.nextDouble(); //had to change depositAmount to depositAmount2 so it would compile (it would not allow a duplicate), it still displays just as the example in the book did however
    System.out.printf("%nadding %.2f to account2 balance%n%n", depositAmount2);
    account2.deposit(depositAmount2);

    System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n", displayAccount(account1)); //40-41
    System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n", displayAccount(account2)); //42-43
}
public static void displayAccount(Account accountToDisplay){
    System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2%n", accountToDisplay.getName(), accountToDisplay.getBalance());
}
}
```

Ok so my goal here is to get it so the displayAccount method displays its name and balance like above (using the data given), and then can be used in the System.out.printf statements instead of the .getName and .getBalance methods. By this I mean instead of using both of those methods I am able to just use account1 (or 2) with .displayAccount (so it would be account1.displayAccount, and yield the same result as if it was with both of the methods). Please help as I am stuck on how to go about doing this.

Comment: Fyree Sorry, I am unable to get what you are actually asking for?

Comment: Sorry, I was vauge in my question. I want to be able to use the displayAccount method in my printf statements instead of all that redundant code. I am trying to get rid of all that repeated code, and just use the displayAccount method instead. Does that help?

Comment: Basically you want to display account name and account balance you are trying to avoid calling getName and getBalance. Just let me know if I am right,.

Comment: Originally I had these statements as this: System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n", account1.getName, account1.getBalance); //13-14
    System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n", account2.getName(), account2.getBalance); . However I want to make it so I do not have to use the that way in order to make this work (I want to be able to use the method displayAccount down below instead that would consolidate the code, and make it less repetative, does that help? Also I edited the code back to its original form.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. I shall post the answer and let me know if that meets your requirement.

Comment: Also I only changed the first two printf statements back to their original form. The others are one of my attempts to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
public class AccountTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Account account1 = new Account("Jane Green", 50.00);
    Account account2 = new Account("John Blue", -7.53);

    displayAccount(account1);
    ...
  }

  public static void displayAccount(Account accountToDisplay) {
    System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f%n",
      accountToDisplay.getName(), accountToDisplay.getBalance());
}
```

Comment: No, it does not say 'you are not permitted to use printf'. Post what it does say.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method printf(String, Object...) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, void), that is the error that I am getting.

Comment: How would I use the method in the bottom in the printf statements?

Comment: I tried yours, and it did not seem to work (although I might just be doing it wrong).

Comment: Q: How would I use the method in the bottom?  A: I just showed you in "main()": simply call "displayAccount()" with the "account" object you want.  Either account1 (as shown), or "account2".  The example assumes you have an "Account.java" class defined somewhere, and that "Account.getName()" returns a string, and "account.getBalance()" returns a floating point value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Account Class that I have created, containing two variables and setter and getter methods. I have also written/ Overridden toString method. Now why toString? Its used to get a string representation of the object. In this particular case the toString method is overridden such that it displays the account name and balance.

```
public class Account {
int balance;
String name;

public int getBalance() {
    return balance;
}
public void setBalance(int balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

return "Name "+this.name+" "+"Balance "+this.balance;
}

**UPDATED CODE**
public String displayAccount(){
    return "Name "+this.name+" "+"Balance "+this.balance;
}


}
```

Client Code

```
package com.StackOverFlow.Doubts4;

public class Dbt7 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Account acc1= new Account();
Account acc2= new Account();
acc1.name="accountHolder1 ";
acc1.balance=111;
acc2.name="accountHolder2 ";
acc2.balance=222;

System.out.println(acc1);
System.out.println(acc2);

**UPDATED**
Dbt7.displayAccount(acc1);
Dbt7.displayAccount(acc2);    
}

**UPDATED**
public static void displayAccount(Account accountToDisplay) {
    System.out.printf("\n\nAccount name "+ accountToDisplay.getName()+ "\nAccount Balance "+ accountToDisplay.getBalance());
}

}
```

the output for the code will be

```
Name accountHolder1  Balance 111
Name accountHolder2  Balance 222
```

I hope this will meet your requirements. let me know if you need anything more.

Note: I have taken a different class on purpose.

**UPDATE**

Comment: This would work, however I am actually doing this as a problem for school, and it needs to be modified exactly as the book requests it to be. I do already have an Account class, but I am somehow supposed to use the displayAccount method in the printf statements to meet the requirements of the problem.

Comment: Can the return type of displayAccount be String?.

Comment: I believe so, as long as it meets the question's requirements.

Comment: I have updated the code, for you. Now lets say if your book needs a display method that does not return a string then all you need to do is to change the return type of the display method from String to void and in the client code you need to call the method on respective object rather than printing it out. eg.acc1.displayAccount();

Comment: Sadly I am unable to change the method, it has to stay as: public static void displayAccount(Account accountToDisplay).

Comment: I have tried that and it did not work, are you able to give me an example in code of what you are talking about?

Comment: I have updated it completely as you require check it.

Comment: welcome, If you are happy with the answer accept it so that it is off from the unanswered hook. 

Once again, I would suggest you to read more on java. Feel free to reach me on my email id( after you have given your 100% ), which I have mentioned in my profile. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same exercise as you, here is the code as you need, no changes are made in class Account.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AccountTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
  

Account account1 = new Account("Jane Green", 50.00);
Account account2 = new Account("John Blue", -7.53);

  // create a Scanner to obtain input from the command window
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  // display initial value, calling the constructor for object account 1 and 2
  displayAccount(account1);
  displayAccount(account2);
  System.out.println();

  // prompt user to enter deposit
  System.out.print("Enter deposit amount for account1: "); // prompt
  double depositAmount = input.nextDouble(); // obtain user input
  System.out.printf("%nadding %.2f to account1 balance%n%n",
          depositAmount);
  account1.deposit(depositAmount); // add to account1's balance

  // Display the new value
  displayAccount(account1);
  displayAccount(account2);
  System.out.println();
  
  // Prompt user to enter deposit
  System.out.print("Enter deposit amount for account2: "); // prompt
  depositAmount = input.nextDouble(); // obtain user input
  System.out.printf("%nadding %.2f to account2 balance%n%n",
          depositAmount);
  account2.deposit(depositAmount); // add to account2 balance

  // Display final value
  displayAccount(account1);
  displayAccount(account2);
  System.out.println();
      
   }

   // Method that displays name and balance of both accounts removing duplicate code.
   public static void displayAccount(Account accountToDisplay) {
  

System.out.printf("%s Balance: %.2f%n", accountToDisplay.getName(), accountToDisplay.getBalance());

   }

}
```