# Unable to have methods from one class use user input from another class in Java

Tags: java, class, methods, user-input, getter-setter

Hello everyone I am having a bit of an issue getting user input from one class to be used in another class' methods (when I try to use the data that was input either nothing shows up, or if something does all of the numbers are zeros). Here are the two classes, the first one containing the setters and getters, and the other class containing the main method in which it takes the user input, is supposed to run it through the methods that are written in the other class, and then print out the results. Here is the first class:

```
public class HeartRates {
//Declaration
public int month;
public int day;
public int year;
public int currentYear;
public int currentAge;
public int maxHeartRate;
public double targetHeartRate50;
public double targetHeartRate85;
public String dateOfBirth = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

//Setters and Getters
public void setMonth(int month){
    this.month = month;
}
public int getMonth(){
    return month;
}

public void setDay(int day){
    this.day = day;
}
public int getDay(){
    return day;
}

public void setYear(int year){
    this.year = year;
}
public int getYear(){
    return year;
}

public String dateOfBirth(){
    return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
}

public void setcurrentYear(int currentYear){
    this.currentYear = currentYear;
}
public int getcurrentYear(){
    return currentYear;
}

//Methods for finding the info
public int currentAge(){
    currentAge = currentYear - year;
    return currentAge;
}
public int maxHeartRate(){
    maxHeartRate = 220 - currentAge;
    return maxHeartRate;
}
public double targetHeartRate50(){
    targetHeartRate50 = maxHeartRate * 0.5;
    return targetHeartRate50;
}
public double targetHeartRate85(){
    targetHeartRate85 = maxHeartRate * 0.85;
    return targetHeartRate85;
}
}
```

and here is the second class that is supposed to take the user input, run it through the methods, and then output the answer:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HeartRatesTest {
    public static void main(String[]args){
    HeartRates HeartRate1 = new HeartRates();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
    String firstName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
    String lastName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter your birth month (interger): ");
    int month = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the day you were born in (integer): ");
    int day = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the year you were born in (full year): ");
    int year = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the current year (full year): ");
    int currentYear = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println(firstName);
    System.out.println(lastName);
    System.out.println("--------");
    System.out.printf(HeartRate1.dateOfBirth);
    System.out.println(HeartRate1.currentAge);
    System.out.println(HeartRate1.maxHeartRate);
    System.out.println(HeartRate1.targetHeartRate50);
}
}
```

I have been at this for hours, and have made very little progress. Again the question is how do I make it so the user input data is used in the methods at the bottom of the first class, and then the resulting data is output to the user using the second class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is lot of work you need to do.

Lets go one by one, 
1)You have created an object of HeartRates, but you are not storing any values into to it. Just defining setters wont do your job. An example for initialization.

```
System.out.print("Enter the year you were born in (full year): ");
HeartRate1.year     = input.nextInt();
```

follow the same for the rest. Now what this does is it stores the input value into an object HeartRate1.( where in HeartRate1-> a variable called year).

2)You are getting zeros? 
These are default values. default values, you get these values when you don't initialize your variables. Try accessing String you will get null.

3)

```
System.out.println(HeartRate1.maxHeartRate);
```

In this case you are trying to access a variable that you have not initialized. so first set the variable by calling the setter method. there is some function and stuffs which you have defined in you class.

4) targetHeartRate50--> you wont get the required output of this methods and its variant as you have not initializing a dependent variable.

All these are hints. Try it.

Comment: I also have another problem that has yet to be solved, if you could help that would be great! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289784/using-another-method-in-main-method. Again thank you for the help on this problem!

Answer (score -1):

Right now you are not calling your setters, do nothing is every set on your object.  All you need are lines like this: `HeartRate1.setYear(currentYear);`
As a side note variables should be lower camel case. So HeartRate1 should be heartRate1.  Also, you should make your class level variables private and be calling the getters in your print statements instead.

Comment: Why and how would I call call the getter in the print statements? Also where am I supposed to put HeartRate1.setYear(currentYear);?

Comment: Its considered bad practice to access variables directly.  Instead of `System.out.println(HeartRate.maxHeartRate);` you would have `System.out.println(HeartRate.getMaxHeartRate());`